# Outlook 2007 not saving sent mail when using IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I have recently setup Outlook 2007 to use with IMAP. I've checked on the option to save sent mail but I've notice that sent mail is not being saved. Any ideas why this might be or how to enable it?

EDIT: I have more information. I've found the sent emails. They're sitting on the local machine in the Personal Folders in the Sent Items folder. So the question should be: How do I change the Sent Items from being stored in that folder to being store in the IMAP sent folder location?

EDIT 2: I've asked the correct question here: [How do I switch default to IMAP file?](https://superuser.com/questions/68571/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tools > account settings (I think, but I have 2010 now so not 100% sure on 2007 location right now), check the data files tab for the different stores in use, choose the 'IMAP' (Exchange?) one and set as default usgin the button for that.

Comment: +1 Thanks AdamV - looks like it will work but "Set as Default" is disabled for that mail box... Any ideas?

Comment: How about using a mail rule in Outlook instead to copy (or ideally move) all sent items to the folder you want them in?

Answer (score 1):

Check this setting:
Tools->Options->Preferences->Email Options->Save Copies of messages in Sent Items Folder (check)

Then...

Tools->Account Settings->(your IMAP account)->More Settings->Folders->(choose your preferred folder)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that its saving the outgoing mail in a 'sent' folder on the IMAP server as opposed to the local Sent folder in outlook.

Comment: I thought of that so I used the web interface to check the sent mail folder and there's nothing in that online folder since the date that I switched to accessing it via Outlook 2007.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more information that I just found.