# How do I switch default data file location to IMAP file in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

In Outlook 2007 I click Tools > Account Settings and then go to the Data Files tab. The current Default mail box is Personal Folders. Above it is my IMAP mail box. I want to switch the Default mail file from Personal to the IMAP one but when the IMAP one is selected the "Set as Default" option is disabled.

How do I enable this option and switch to IMAP as the default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

The way IMAP is implemented in Outlook it does not support IMAP as a default default data file.

This is because the IMAP protocol is only designed for the storage of e-mails. Outlook needs to store other types of objects like contacts, notes, appointments etc. which (officially) are not supported by the IMAP protocol.

AFIK only .PST files, Microsoft Exchange accounts and a couple of third-party groupware accounts (via add-ons) can be be used as the default "Message Store" (that's how the data file is called internally).

Comment: @Albic - what does the "default" data file/message store actually mean in Windows/Outlook?  What happens with the data file specified as default?

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old post just in case anyone else has this issue.

This is not a solution, but may provide a workaround depending on the behavior you're looking for.

In Outlook 2007, go to Tools - Options - Other - Advanced Options - "Startup in this folder:", click the Browse button and choose the IMAP inbox you want in the folder tree.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything else, I resorted to making a NTFS link to force the folder into another drive. This seems to be the only way to define location of IMAP email datafile freely, which is unbelievable.

Registry editing e.g. ForcePSTPath did not work either.

The command prompt commands:

```
mklink /D C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook F:\Emails
```

You need to be raised to administrator privileges to run the command, but afterwards the emails will appear into F:\Email (or whatever you choose as the target).

The original Outlook folder contents should be moved to F:\Emails and then deleted, before making the link.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Account Settings – below the E-mail tab click New.
2. Choose the E-mail Service as POP3.
3. Click “manually configure server settings or additional server types” check box. This will automatically enter in all of the required fields.
4. Click Next.
5. Click the Internet E-mail bubble.
6. Click Next.
7. Enter the following information:

   - Your Name: Display Name you want to use, e.g.., Joe Smith
   - Email address: Full email address, e.g., username@example.com
   - Incoming Server: Contact your ISP or Hosting Company for this setting, e.g., mail.example.com
   - Outgoing Mail server: Contact your ISP or Hosting Company for this setting, e.g., mail.example.com
   - User name: Full email address, e.g., username@example.com
   - Password: Your email account password
8. If your mail server requires SMTP Authentication, follow these steps. If you are not sure if your mail server requires SMTP Authentication, please contact your hosting company or ISP.

   - Click on More Settings.
   - Navigate to Outgoing Server Tab
   - Check "My Outgoing Server requires SMTP Authentication".
   - Click OK.
9. Click Next, then Finish.
10. In the datafile set your new accout as default.

Comment: This is wrong. The person is asking about IMAP not POP3 there is a big difference between IMAP and POP3.